# JSF issue, SelectManyListBox created in js, do not getting the value in Form Bean

Tags: jsf

I have Two SelectManyListBox in jsf, In the basis of 1st one i added options in 2nd list box in JS.
when i submit the form then do not get the value of 2nd SelectManyListBox.
i am using jsf 1.0

Please help how to access the value of 2nd one.
thank you.

Comment: Provide [mcve] or this question will be closed.

Comment: You cannot add options client-side. That is 'tampering' with data and is one of the great automatic features of JSF since it does not expect one of these values and not only ignores them, but will even give you an error message. And seriously... JSF1.0? Please move on (or tell your employer to)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF validation for client side injected elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117795/jsf-validation-for-client-side-injected-elements)